# How to pass runtime variable to validation routine in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, xaml

I have a wpf window with a ComboBox and a TextBox (and lots of other stuff not relevant here).  I am trying to write a validation routine in VB for the TextBox.  In my XAML I have

```
<TextBox>
    <Binding
        Path="Charge"
        UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <e:VR />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox>
```

where VR is my validation routine and e is an assembly containing VR that is in my project references.

The problem I am having is VR needs to know the SelectedValue of the ComboBox in order to know how to perform the validation.  How do I get that value into the validation routine?

Comment: Just guessing here, but can you add a dependency property to your ValidationRule and bind it to the SelectedValue of your ComboBox?

Answer (score 0):

You can have public properties inside VR which can be set while declaring the validation rule like this :

```
public class VR : ValidationRule
{ 
    public VR()
    {

    }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SetSelectedValueProperty= 
     DependencyProperty.Register("SetSelectedValue", typeof(string), typeof(VR), new 
        PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetSelectedValuePropertyChanged))); 

  public string SetSelectedValue { 
     get { return (string)GetValue(SetSelectedValueProperty); } 
     set { SetValue(SetSelectedValueProperty, value); } 

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {

    }      

    private static void OnSetSelectedValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { 
     // Some code 
  } 
}
```

Set the SelectedValue in XAML like this :

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <e:VR SetSelectedValue="{Binding ElementName="ComboBox1", Path=SelectedValue.Content}"/>
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for - Thanks.  However, I get the following error: "A binding cannot be set on the 'SelectedValue' property of type 'VR'.  A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: Replaced with a dependency property. Check answer now.